# Работа с массивом в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, массивы, postgresql, запрос

Есть две таблицы: grades (которая содержит оценки студентов университета) и students (данные о самих студентов). Передо мной стоит задача вывести имена и фамилии студентов-"должников", заваливших экзамены (соответственно оценка 0 - не явился и 2 - не сдал). Для этого я написал следующую функцию:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.show_badstudents()
 RETURNS TABLE(first_name character varying, second_name character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$DECLARE
bad int[];
BEGIN
SELECT grade_student into bad from grades 
WHERE
grade = 2
or grade = 0;
RETURN QUERY SELECT student_firstName,student_secondName FROM students
where student_id = ANY(bad);
END; $function$
```

Суть такова: в функции создается массив (bad) и в него заносятся id студентов, у которых в базе оценок нашлись "0" или "2". При вызове функции появляется ошибка: **malformed array literal "5"**. Насколько я понял, веду работу с массивом неправильно.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться! Извините, если вопрос тривиальный, совсем новичок в PostgreSQL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bad int[];
BEGIN
SELECT grade_student into bad from grades 
WHERE
grade = 2
or grade = 0;
```

Если вы подумали, что `select column into array_variable` сделает массив вместо вас - это не так.

Синтаксис [`select into` в plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) оперирует только первой строкой результата. Но предупреждения об этом языком выведено не будет. Будет ошибка только если указать `STRICT`

Таким образом здесь вы значение колонки grade_student первой попавшейся строки пытаетесь присвоить массиву, что, конечно, некорректно. Неочевидное сообщение об ошибке от того, что вызывается функция парсера литерала массива - значение массива может быть записано в строковом формате.

---

Чтобы получить то что вы хотели - вам необходимо сформировать массив в самом запросе:

```
SELECT array_agg(grade_student) into bad from grades 
WHERE
grade = 2
or grade = 0;
```

И таким образом присвоить переменной уже сформированный массив.

Впрочем, в этой функции массив не нужен вовсе. Задача проще решается одним запросом сразу, а потому более простого language sql достаточно даже для хранимки.